KDE Plasma/Wayland is unable to lock lockfile /run/user/1000/wayland-0.lock
When running dbus-run-session startplasma-wayland, I see this error constantly reoccuring: dbus-daemon[7000]: [session uid=1000 pid=7000] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1. I assume this is why KDE Plasma 6 doesn't start, and I get a black screen with a cursor (and whatever programs are set to autostart). I think it might have to do with these errors:
unable to lock lockfile /run/user/1000/wayland-0.lock, maybe another compositor is running
unable to lock lockfile /run/user/1000/wayland-1.lock, maybe another compositor is running

If another compositor is running, I have no idea how to detect it. This started happening after I upgraded to Fedora KDE 40.
How can I troubleshoot this?

Is it necessary for you to use dbus-run-session for that?

Isn’t that what you’re supposed to do?

Update: Apparently you don't necessarily need that. But when I run the same command without dbus-run-session, I get "Could not start d-bus. Can you call qdbus?"

Well, typically not on a systemd system – there you're supposed to already have a "user bus" running all the time (which is the only one that org.freedesktop.systemd1 would be available on) – generally the only times you need to do it manually are a) not a systemd distro or b) specifically want a second dbus instance isolated from the main one. In your case, what does systemctl --user status dbus show?

Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

How do you log in to the system? The lack of both the user bus and /run/user/X in general usually means either pam_systemd is not working or you're "logging in" in a way that doesn't call PAM.

If I get what you mean, I log into the system using SDDM.

Hello @u1686_grawity, can you perhaps join this chat? I still have this issue.
